# Gmail integration with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, gmail

I am trying to build a Chrome extension that can recognize clicks on a mail in Gmail and will fetch all the email IDs that are in to, cc, bcc, and body of the mail clicked. I want these fetched IDs to be searched in my extension for which I already have a search API and just want to accomplish the task where a user can click on the mail in Gmail and this will automatically trigger the search in my extension with the email IDs fetched from that email chain.

I tried  adding a listener but could not figure out a way to read the content from the web-page and also want something more reliable like if there is a Gmail API for this and how to implement this.